# Applying an XSLT Transform to a DataSet (ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, xslt, ado.net, dataset

There is a nice example on the Microsoft Website (Even vor .Net 4)

```
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDataDocument = New XmlDataDocument(dataSet) 

Dim xslTran As XslTransform = New XslTransform 
xslTran.Load("transform.xsl")

Dim writer As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter("xslt_output.html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, Nothing, writer)
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/8fd7xytc

No unfortunately XmlDataDocument is deprecated, but nobody seems to have a good answer on how to replace it in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code.

Use [`DataSet.GetXml()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml.aspx) to get the xml as string and then create an XDocument by parsing the string:

```
string xml = dataSet.GetXml();
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

The setup of the transformation and its output is the same, except using XslCompiledTransform:

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load("transform.xsl");
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("Output.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

And then you can use the [`XslCompiledTransform.Transform()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163433.aspx) overload that takes a reader as the first argument, which you can get from calling [`XDocument.CreateReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.createreader.aspx):

```
transform.Transform(Document.CreateReader(), writer);
```

Comment: Ok, is there no direct way without the detour via String?

Comment: There's this answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808427/dataset-to-xdocument-conversion-and-back/3809024#3809024. But that's even more of a detour using serialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I looked at that too. But figured if this class gets deprecated there should be a good workaround. But I guess string it is.